# How to sort directories by date based on their most recently updated files or subdirectories in Windows OS

Tags: windows

How can I sort directories by date in File Explorer such that it sorts directories based on the modification date of any file or subdirectory within that directory (not the modification date of the directory itself)? I couldn't find a way to do this from File Explorer.

For example, the modification date of a file in Folder 2 is newer than the modification date of a file in Folder 1. However, Folder 1 is listed above  Folder 2.

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks. Could you post this as an answer so I can close the issue?

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer and removed the comment for everyone's convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in explorer.

Explorer sorts files and folders separate from eachother, and it shows it correctly.

New to old (or old to new if you sort the descending instead of ascending), and it takes the time into consideration as well.

If you want different sorting, you will have to make changes manually. For example, include the date at the start of the folder, then sort by name.